# RFID tags emulation in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, nfc

Right now, you have to use fakeTagsActivity ( http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/simulator/FakeTagsActivity.html) if you want to test tags with your android application.
Do the Android team plan to include this feature in to the emulator, so you could create RFID tags and "connect" them to the phone just with a click?
 This thing was implemented very well in 2 years old Nokia NFC Manager that came with Nokia 6212 ( http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/5bcaee40-d2b2-4595-b5b5-4833d6a4cda1/S40_Nokia_6212_NFC_SDK.html).

Somehow off topic, are there any good code samples for using NFC in Android besides those at official page?

Thank you.

Comment: The emulator doesn't support many sensors at all (accelerometer, light, etc. aren't supported) and it's unlikely that it will any time soon. The 'official' line has always been to use a real device to test stuff like this.

Comment: I was afraid of official line like that. Hope that changes in the near future, because it would be handy to test nfc apps properly in the emulator, because nexus s is currenty the only android nfc phone on the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. The emulator is nice to do some basic development and testing. But for the more advanced topics (like nfc) you have to use a real device.

And because it's really easy to deploy and debug on a real target, it's not likely that it will be implemented on the emulator.

Next to this, there is the fact that the Android Emulator is open source. So, you could add it yourself if you want.

Comment: If you use hardware for testing, how do you test on different versions of Android?

Comment: Use different kinds of hardware devices? 
At this time I think there are not many devices with NFC. In the market are only the Google Nexus S and the US version of the Samsung Galaxy S2 as far as I know. So you don't have to buy many of them. Besides that NFC is only available from Android 2.3.3 and higher. So there aren't many version with NFC support yet to test on.